# Como fazer scroll posicionar div por uma imagem

Tags: html, css

Estou usando um script que quando acionado me posiciona em uma `div` específica, está funcionando, mas o código que tenho faz isso a partir de um `link` de texto e estou tentando adapta-lo para uma imagem e que a mesma fique posionada acima de uma outra `div`.
A imagem do que preciso é essa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O script que tenho é esse:

O que aciona:

```
    <a href="#bottom" id="top">Clique para Posiconar</a>
```

O que posiciona:

```
$('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function(event) {
var target = $( $(this).attr('href') );
if( target.length ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
    }, 1000);
}
```

});

A página com o código em funcionamento até o momento pode ser vista aqui:

[Exemplo](http://topdeia.com.br/modelos/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para fazer o mesmo com uma div, vc pode inserir um atributo como "data-href" e se basear nele. Ficaria assim:

$('.classe_da_div').on('click', function(event) {
var target = $( $(this).attr('data-href') );
  event.preventDefault();
  $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: target.offset().top
  }, 1000);
});